# How to insert a row into snowflake table that have a field with a type VARIANT?

Tags: sql, cloud, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant

I am trying to insert a row into snowflake table having the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE dataSources  (
  dataSources_id integer,   
  sourceName varchar (100),
  sourceData VARIANT, 
  created_at timestamp
);
```

I need to insert a json file into the `sourceData` field along with other info about the source itself:

```
INSERT INTO dataSources (dataSources_id, sourceName, sourceData, created_at)
VALUES (1, 'Source 1', ..., '2020-11-18 00:00:00')
```

The `sourceData` field is a variant, and I need to put a JSON file in it to be uploaded with other data.

I tried to use:

```
PUT C://path/file.json @internal_stage
```

I have got an error of:

> PUT is not recognized

I tried to add it directly into the query:

```
INSERT INTO dataSources (dataSources_id, sourceName, sourceData, created_at)
VALUES (1, 'Source 1', PUT C://path/file.json @internal_stage, '2020-11-18 00:00:00')
```

But it didn't work with an error of SQL Syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PUT is a SnowSQL command, you can not run it through Web UI yet:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use.html

After putting the file into @internal_stage, you can use COPY command:

```
COPY INTO dataSources (dataSources_id, sourceName, sourceData, created_at) 
FROM (SELECT 1, 'Source 1', $1, '2020-11-18 00:00:00'
FROM @internal_stage ) FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=JSON);
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

If the JSON content is not in a file, you can also use this query to insert that row:

```
INSERT INTO dataSources (dataSources_id, sourceName, sourceData, created_at) 
SELECT 1, 'Source 1', parse_json('{ "name":"test","age":20 }'), '2020-11-18 00:00:00';
```

Comment: The problem is that I am not able to put the JSON file into a stage

Comment: you need to use SnowSQL to put (upload) the file into stage. I shared the link of snowsql - it's a CLI tool which works on your own laptop. please try it

Comment: just one more thing, I am trying to run snowSQL using `snowsql.exe -a myaccount -u myuser -p mypassword` but its returning that -p is not properly defined

Comment: Not familiar with windows version, but as I see, -p means port and it's deprecated https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-start.html#connection-parameters-reference